# How to change pointed index in Material-UI's DropDown Menu

Tags: material-ui

This is a very specific documentation question, so you either know it because you've used Material-UI or you don't.

I'm using Material-UI's [Dropdown Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.7.1/#/components/dropdown-menu) and I'd like to know if there's a way to tell it which selectedIndex value to have, since I'm constantly changing its menuItems and worry it might end up in an illegal state (index out of range).

I'm using Material-UI v0.7.1. I am aware the current version is v0.14.4 but it would be complicated to update.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the [drop-down-menu.jsx](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v0.7.1/src/js/drop-down-menu.jsx) on the [v0.7.1 GitHub repo](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v0.7.1), I realized it's as simple as doing

`dropdownMenu.setState({selectedIndex: val});`

Where

- `dropdownMenu` is the DropdownMenu React component, and
- `val` is the desired index.

Beware that this will not call the `onChange()` function of the dropdown, and also that this is true for v0.7.1.